# QtWebKit not found by OpenLayers Plugin

Tags: qgis

I have Yakkety installed on my PC.

I have installed Quantum GIS 2.18 using the installation process described in the link https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu. I used the debian method.

I am trying to use the OpenLayers Plugin, which is trusted by the QGIS S/W.

While enabling the plugin, it screams that it requires QtWebKit, which although installed on the PC, is not found by QGIS. Apparently QtWebKit (as required by QGIS) is for QT4, but Yakkety is on Qt5.

Although this issue is reported as a bug here (https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15128), what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I am a devoted user of QGIS for several years and I was confronted to the same problem and resolved it by using the tile server (x, g) in which I created a new connection with this URL " https: // mt1.google.com / vt / lyrs=s*x = { x } *y = *z = { z } "

It is enough, then, to add the layer so created and we obtain the Google satellite view.

No more need to use openlayers plugin